# Как активировать элемент веб страницы? (bs4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

При парсинге одного сайта невозможно увидеть цены, пока не нажмешь на кнопку выбора города.

```html
<input type="submit" name="yes" value="Да" kl_vkbd_parsed="true">
```

как можно нажать на нее средствами bs4?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: выполнить запрос, который выполняет эта кнопка

Comment: Виталий Шебаниц можете подробнее написать как это сделать а то все говорят что нужно выполнить запрос а как походу никто не знает)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> как можно нажать на нее средствами bs4?

Никак. `bs4` – библиотека парсинга `xml`/`html`, а не сетевая библиотека.

Можно посмотреть через инспектор браузера (обычно на <kbd>F12</kbd> вызывается) какой запрос отправляется при клике на ту кнопку и повторить ее через `requests`, `urlopen` или другую удобную вам библиотеку.

Вот [пример авторизации](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5792e2a8e3b5506b05471f86aedae90c4e7bcbc9/requests_example/auth__newlms_magtu_ru.py) через подсмотренный запрос:

```
import requests
session = requests.session()

rs = session.post('http://newlms.magtu.ru/login/index.php', data={'username': LOGIN, 'password': PASSWORD})
print(rs)

# Если логин / пароль правильный, случится переход на главную страницу
success = rs.url == 'http://newlms.magtu.ru/'
print(success)

if success:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'lxml')

    print('Меню:')
    for a in root.select('a.menu-action'):
        print('    {} -> {}'.format(a.text, a['href']))
```

---

Можно использовать специализированные библиотеки, например `robobrowser`, которые смогут автоматизировать такие действия как заполнение данных на форме, отправка формы (клик на кнопку) и получение данных.

Вот [для примера авторизация](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e5b51c694478a6110f14765e4bc16c58663bb8ad/robobrowser_examples/github__login_and_print_email_from_settings.py) на гитхабе:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser(
    user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
    parser='lxml'
)
browser.open('https://github.com/login')

signup_form = browser.get_form()
signup_form['login'].value = LOGIN
signup_form['password'].value = PASSWORD

# Submit the form
browser.submit_form(signup_form)

browser.open('https://github.com/settings/emails')

for tag in browser.select('#settings-emails > li > span.css-truncate-target'):
    print(tag.text)
```

---

Другой вариант, более человечный -- использовать `selenium`. В `selenium` используется браузер для работы с сайтами и позволяет кликать, нажимать и т.п.

Пример [авторизации через клик](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f071aadf145a168f6929a88d3d1e649f03852334/selenium__examples/auth__vk.com/main.py) на кнопку логина:

```
...
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://vk.com/')

driver.find_element_by_id('index_email').send_keys(LOGIN)
driver.find_element_by_id('index_pass').send_keys(PASSWORD)

driver.find_element_by_id("index_login_button").click()
...
```