# Форма с XHR и авторизация на "бота" на сайте

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, веб-программирование, http, xmlhttprequest

На сайте есть форма авторизации, при отправке которой посылается xhr запрос **ajax.php** файлу с таким же названием. В теле, соответственно данные (пароль и логин) из формы. Так я вхожу в свой аккаунт. А какими способами можно сделать так, чтобы в этот же аккаунт "вошел" мой бот, написанный на Python? Хотя даже не важно что на Python, что искать?

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852494/201445

Comment: @gil9red Не выходит. Возможно потому что на сайте нет отдельной страницы вроде login.php, а форма просто появляется при нажатии на кнопку, а куда она отправляется я уже говорил. Вот сам сам сайт https://csgopositive.com/

Comment: не имеет значение есть та страница или нет, нужно смотреть какой запрос отправляется (POST/GET), какое тело (если запрос POST) и/или какие параметры с ним уходят. И это повторить в своем запросе на сайт. Да и иногда заголовки запроса нужны -- для того же xhr. Смогу примерно через 7 часов посмотреть ту ссылку -- корпоративная прокси не пропускает

Comment: @gil9red огромное спасибо

Comment: Спасибо потому что сами разобрались по подсказке или наперед благодарите за то, что посмотрю? Оо

Comment: @gil9red И то и другое, пожалуй.

Comment: Забудьте про бота :) У меня при попытке входа кроме почты и пароля, капчу запросил :) в таком случае задача будет сложнее и ее можно попробовать ее обойти через selenium, но и то сомнительно :)

Comment: @ gil9red Хорошо, забуду, раз уж так, то можно пример кода, который выполняет авторизацию на том сайте(будто мы в идеальном мире где нет капчи) на будущее, чтобы знал;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повторил запрос авторизации, который выполняется при клике на `ВОЙТИ`:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer': 'https://csgopositive.com/',
}

data = {
    'action': 'auth',
    'login': 'my@email.ru',
    'password': '1234',
    'lang': 'RU',
    'g-recaptcha-response': '12A444kEkmbxr5MUU0oCX777Ua4Mf4rWgEfodfSmqQyNr5OOIbtaD669kW3sG9v99TBRk0WGaWhg198qVsisBtm2eSCFQbUqSbcnQrPB1-MrMRwwY05mEBhmYqeaLxcybgjwQbkffe71z2IRGme3I3-2FJ7wvUqcSJSISGXMaIViznWbl78cvPq-b0fpxDTnTkV8VQ9iGKuwAHfe4eR-0js3vOFH74tHsUQiDDhobOfjDhUXwM6fUg3gosp6pfIpEO11-HnPUC01JT0LDj59c2eHODiUBupLfZAA',
}

rs = requests.post('https://csgopositive.com/lib/ajax.php', headers=headers, data=data)
print(rs)       # <Response [200]>

# Если токен капчи будет невалидный, отсутствующий или просроченный, 
# то придет: "Вы не прошли капчу!"
print(rs.text)  # Неверный логин или пароль
```

Большую часть заголовков запроса убрал – и без них запрос проходит. User-Agent тоже необязательный, но для ботов лучше иметь User-Agent браузера.

Comment: Ха! Спасибо вообще то, но странно, почему у меня ничего не выходило, ведь я делал все почти также.