# Как сделать чтобы парсер мог "нажать кнопку"

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, telegram-bot, requests

Я делаю теграмм бота, в нем есть кнопка факты, я нашел сайт с генератором фактов и там есть кнопка  - сгенерировать факт, мне надо "нажать кнопку" не открывая браузер, это возможно?

```
 def get_fact(url, headers):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    button = soup.find_all("button", class_="fact")

    fact = soup.find_all("tr", class_="td")
    return fact
```

Я сам глупость написал, но просто чтоб вы поняли

Comment: дайте ссылку на сайт, если не трудно.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup библиотека для красивого парсинга. Нужно использовать библиотеки, использующие драйвер браузера

Или как предложил человек по [источнику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852334/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-bs4):

Можно посмотреть через инспектор браузера (обычно на <kbd>F12</kbd> вызывается) какой запрос отправляется при клике на ту кнопку и повторить ее через `requests`, `urlopen` или другую удобную вам библиотеку.

Вот [пример авторизации](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5792e2a8e3b5506b05471f86aedae90c4e7bcbc9/requests_example/auth__newlms_magtu_ru.py) через подсмотренный запрос:

```
import requests
session = requests.session()

rs = session.post('http://newlms.magtu.ru/login/index.php', data={'username': LOGIN, 'password': PASSWORD})
print(rs)

# Если логин / пароль правильный, случится переход на главную страницу
success = rs.url == 'http://newlms.magtu.ru/'
print(success)

if success:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'lxml')

    print('Меню:')
    for a in root.select('a.menu-action'):
        print('    {} -> {}'.format(a.text, a['href']))
```

Comment: я все равно не понимаю как реализовать эту функцию

Answer (score 0):

Я решил свой вопрос: я попробовал код, который просто парсит факты и это сработало, оно каждый раз давало рандомный факт

```
def get_fact(url, headers):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    # button = soup.find_all("button", class_="fact")
    fact = soup.find_all("table", class_="text")
    clear_facts = [x.text for x in fact]
                    
    return clear_facts
```